# send email using mandrill not working (already have openssl)

Tags: mandrill

Im from Indonesia, please forgive me if my language is not as good as others

About a week ago i host my site in UK web hosting company, and few days ago i moved them into USA web hosting company. Previously i manage to get my registration page sending a registration email when there's a new user register to my site. I used swift mailer and mandrill. but after i moved into the new web hosting company, it doesnt send any email at all.

already have the username email similar like the old one, already check that the openssl already available in the php config, but still not sending

is there anyone who is good at mandrill and willing to help me? hence, from the code side, it doesnt change at all(still the same like before).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your new hosting company may be blocking the port being used or limit outbound SMTP connections.

Comment: my hosting company only limited the IP to 26 and 465(SSL), i already try to change it into 465 from my code. Something like: $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.mandrillapp.com', 465, 'ssl'); but still cant access.. For the error log: [30-Apr-2013 00:42:01] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host smtp.mandrillapp.com [Connection timed out #110]' in /home3/prec9/public_html/libraries/swift/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:259  is there something that i need to set into our server? Thx

Comment: Even though they said that they opened the port for SMTP, it looks like there's an issue reaching the servers. This might be because the port is open, but not for external SMTP connections. You'll probably want to get in touch with them again to be sure you can access and use external SMTP providers.